# Accessing Object inside Array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to access values inside Firebase array > object.
[image]

When I try to access values inside v-for, it works well. But I cannot do this: postDetail.author. It returns undefined. What's the solution?

Comment: Please post CODE instead of PICTURES of code. You want `postDetail[0].author`

Comment: what you have tried so far ?

Comment: postDetail is an array and you want to access first item of it..so you need to do `postDetail[0].author`

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._

Answer (score 3):

Since postDetail is an array of object to access properties inside its objects, you need do something like `postDetail[Index].prop`

```js
var postDetail =[{"author" : "abc", "meta" : "xyz"}];
console.log(postDetail[0].author);
```

Comment: and just for fun,  with destructuring `const [{author},] = [{"author" : "abc", "meta" : "xyz"}];
console.log(author);` :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want get only `author` try it:

```js
var postDetails = [{
  author: "John",
  category: "Tech"
}];

var inner = postDetails.map(function(e) {
  return e.autor;
});

console.log(inner);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Array of object
var persons = [
  {
    name: "shubham",
    age: 22,
    comments: ["Good", "Awesome"]
  },
  {
    name: "Ankit",
    age: 24,
    comments: ["Fine", "Decent"]
  },
  {
    name: "Arvind",
    age: 26,
    comments: ["Awesome", "Handsome"]
  },
  {
    name: "Ashwani",
    age: 28,
    comments: ["Very Good", "Lovely"]
  }
];

var data = persons.map(person => {
  console.log(person.name);
  console.log(person.age);
  person.comments.map((comment, index) => console.log(index + " " + comment));
});
```