# Can't access array after passing it to state, but can access it before

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an pseudo-object is inside my state. I've been able to access through a couple layers, but when I reach the array inside the object Im getting undefined errors.

UPDATE: Its something wrong with how I pass lambdaReturnObject to the state which isn't letting me access the array, tested with `lambdaReturnObject.campaigns[0].campaignName` and it worked.

```
handleSearch() {
    //data to use to query backend
    let campaignId = this.refs.campaignInput.value
    let marketplace = this.refs.marketplaceInput.value

    //using local copy of backend data, production should call backend fo this instead
    let lambdaReturn = "{\"advertiser\":{\"advertiserId\":\"1\",\"enforcedBudget\":0.1},\"campaigns\":[{\"campaignID\":\"1\",\"campaignName\":\"fake\",\"createDate\":11111,\"creationDate\":1111,\"startDate\":1111,\"endDate\":1111,\"dailyBudget\":0.1,\"internal\":{\"budgetCurrencyCode\":\"USD\",\"inBudget\":true},\"enforcedBudget\":0.1,\"budgetCurrencyCode\":\"USD\",\"budgetPacingStrategy\":\"asp\",\"budgetType\":\"averageDaily\",\"status\":\"enables\",\"internalStatus\":\"enabled\"}],\"campaignID\":\"1\"}"
    let lambdaReturnObject = JSON.parse(lambdaReturn)

    this.setState({
      apiData: lambdaReturnObject
    })
  }
```

When I try and go to the array inside, I get the following error

`<h3>Campaigns :{console.log(this.state.apiData.campaigns[0].campaignName)}</h3>`

`Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

This means I am accessing it the wrong way, but I looked at other posts ([Accessing Object inside Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50822205/accessing-object-inside-array)) and I thought that this was right. Though I am definitely wrong or else I wouldn't be writing this.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the code of your call to fetch from the api? It sounds like an asynchronous issue.

Comment: the fetch to the api is just a String that I use JSON.parse on, Im not actually calling backend, but it would be the same JSONString, let me add it to the question though

Comment: Given your code, I have no idea what the issue could be. It all looks like it should work. I can at least confirm that `campaigns[0]` is definitely the way you’d access the first item in the `campaigns` array though.

Comment: I called ```lambdaReturnObject.campaigns[0].campaignName``` and it worked. So I am doing something wrong when it comes to setting the state ```apiData: lambdaReturnObject```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was that `render()` calls right as the page is booted up. At that time the object is not stored in my state so trying to call

`this.state.objects.innerObject.property`

would fail because I declared objects in my state, innerObject could be counted as null before the object is actually loaded in so it wouldn't throw an error. But property would throw an error because innerObject as we know, is null.

Fix by using an if statement before rendering the page to see if the object is actually loaded in. If not render just default empty JSX.

Answer (score 1):

JSON.parse() is synchronous function, so set state wont be called till, JSON.parse() executes completely and returns the object.

Still You can try following

1. Call JSON.parse() using a try-catch block like below and see if it works. Also it is error free way of parsing your stringified objects.

   try {
   let lambdaReturnObject = JSON.parse(lambdaReturn)
   this.setState({
   apiData: lambdaReturnObject
   })object
   }
   catch (err) {
   // Do error handling here.
   }
2. Use optional chaining, and try to access your object like  `this.state.apiData.campaigns?.[0].campaignName`; this won't give error even if compaigns is undefined.

Refer : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Comment: Wow that last thing with optional chaining makes it work thanks! But I added some more info in the question so that might also point to the original problem, I will use this way if I can't solve it when setting the state.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what is happening. The call to get campaigns[0] is getting resolved before the API call finishes. You can try a promise or async await to make sure the object is retrieved from the API call before you attempt to access it.

Do you happen to have a code snippet of is being used to get the data?

Comment: Im sorry, another comment also asked that, I just added how I am getting the object now